# WordPress: How to handle a post request for non logged in users when the form works for logged in users

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a form in single-$post_type.php which sends data over to my themes functions file. The form posts fine when the user is logged in.

But if the user is not logged in then the form just fails and reloads the home page.

In short, the form is a job application form. The form sends all the data to the function, the function creates two emails and sends them both out to the HR and the Candidate. Then redirects to a thank you page.

**THE FORM PROCESSOR IN FUNCTIONS.PHP**

```
add_action( 'admin_post_nopriv_email_appliaction_form', 'processform' );
add_action( 'admin_post_email_appliaction_form', 'processform' );

function processform() {
  //Handle the CV Upload
  require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );
  require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
  require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php' );         

  $attachment_id = media_handle_upload( 'cv', $_POST['post_id'] );
  $attachments = get_attached_file( $attachment_id );

  //Get variables for emai content
  $jobTitle = $_POST['jobTitle']; 
  $jobLocation = $_POST['jobLocation'];
  $fullName = $_POST['fullName'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $telephone = $_POST['tel'];
  $quickmessage = strip_tags ( $_POST['message'] );

  $to = $_POST['email'];
  $admin_email = get_option( 'admin_email' );

  //Build the message to the candidate
  $messageCandidate = email_header();
  $messageCandidate .= candidate_application($jobTitle, $jobLocation);
  $messageCandidate .= reason_jobapplication();
  $messageCandidate .= email_footer();

  //Build the message to the head office
  $messageOffice = email_header();
  $messageOffice .= new_candidate_application($jobTitle, $jobLocation, $fullName, $email, $telephone, $quickmessage);
  $messageOffice .= reason_new_jobapplication();
  $messageOffice .= email_footer();


  $headers[] = 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8';
  $headers[] = 'From: Greenfield IT Recruitment <info@greenfield-it.co.uk>';

  $mailCandidate = wp_mail($to, 'Application successfull', $messageCandidate, $headers );
  $mailoffice = wp_mail($admin_email, 'New Candidate Application', $messageOffice, $headers, array($attachments) );

  if ($mailCandidate) {
      wp_delete_attachment( $attachment_id, true );
      wp_redirect( get_site_url().'?p=227');
      exit;
  }



}
```

**THE HTML FORM IN SINGLE-$POST_TYPE.PHP**

```
   <form id="jobApplication" name="jobApplication" action="<?php echo esc_url( admin_url('admin-post.php') ); ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return validation(this)">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input type="text" name="fullName" placeholder="Full Name: (required)" required>
            <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email: (required)" required>
            <input type="tel" name="tel" placeholder="Telephone: (required)" required>
            <textarea name="message" placeholder="Quick message"></textarea>
            <span>Please upload a copy of your cv in .doc or .docx format. We will accept a pdf.</span>
            <span><input type="file" name="cv" accept="application/pdf" required></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <p><strong>Protecting your data</strong><br>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="email_appliaction_form">
            <input type="hidden" name="jobTitle" value="<?php the_title(); ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="jobLocation" value="<?php echo $meta['city'][0]; ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="post_id" id="post_id" value="<?php the_id(); ?>" />
            <input type="submit" class="btn" name="submit">
        </div>
    </form>
```

Happy to post the rest of the code in the funciton if need be.

Thanks

Comment: We can not do anything with 2 lines of code.. Please would you provide us with more code

Comment: it will be helpful if your include "wordpress" in your title and description

Comment: Updated. Thanks.

Comment: @Tomm 
Would you like to see the form as well?

Comment: That would be usefull.

Comment: @Tomm
Updated, thanks

Comment: @AlexKnopp If you hide the form to non-logged in users, would that work as a solution for you?

Comment: @AlexKnopp Because if that's not a solution then that means you will need to force a login before on submit. Or if the user is not even registered, that means they'll need to register, activate their account etc.

Comment: @ProEvilz
So your suggesting if it doesnt work, hide it under the carpet lol. 
No it needs to work for non logged in users. Logged in users use a different method to apply for vacancies.

Comment: Yes... hide stuff that non-logged in users are not supposed to see. You didn't specify any of this in your question so I had to assume. 

You now need to reword your question to: How can I force login &/or registration on form submit" or something like that. As right now, you will get solutions to your problem specifically... and hiding the form solves that specific problem.

Comment: @ProEvilz. I don't want to force log in and the question is clear. The question reads, "how to handle post requests for non logged in user...s". My description clearly states that the form fails for non logged in users, giving the impression that non logged in users need to use it. If they didn't then hiding the form wouldn't be the solution either, showing the form using a conditional check would. At no point did I say that non logged in users should NOT see the form.

Comment: "how to handle post requests for non logged in user" - solution: make them log in. You didn't specify whether you wanted to do this or **not**

Comment: @ProEvilz. But then they wouldnt be "non logged in users", they would be "logged in users". The question states for "non logged in users".

Comment: They would before they submit the form.... only after applying the solution of logging them in do they become logged in.... and at the point of applying the 'solution', the problem is then solved.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155748/discussion-between-alex-knopp-and-proevilz).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I experienced this problem and had the exact same 'blockusers_init' code snippet you used (which I can't seem to find where it came from originally). Anyway, I added a couple of lines to let the admin_post file through (inspired by [this](http://natko.com/block-access-to-wp-admin-and-wordpress-dashboard/))...

```
add_action( 'init', 'blockusers_init' );
function blockusers_init() {
    $file = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    if ( is_admin() && ! current_user_can( 'administrator' ) && 
      ! ( defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) && DOING_AJAX ) &&
      ( $file != 'admin-post.php')) {
        wp_redirect( home_url() );
        exit;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason this wasnt working was because there was a function inside the theme I had added that restricted access to wp-admin to admin only. This requried you to be logged in, other wise it would redirect the home page. 
I am yet to find a workaround.

```
add_action( 'init', 'blockusers_init' );
 function blockusers_init() {
  if ( 
  is_admin() && ! current_user_can( 'administrator' ) && 
  ! ( defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) && DOING_AJAX )  &&
  ! ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') )
   {
   wp_redirect( home_url() );
   exit;
 }
}
```